# WordPress - limit total post and paging number

Tags: wordpress

Is possible to limit two option:

1. posts Total
2. paging number

For example: I have 20 posts, and i only want get 10 posts and paging them (4 post per view)?

I using below code but it only do 4 items per view and get all 20 posts?

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
     'posts_per_page' => 4,
  )
);
```

How to do that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the paged element to get the pagination and pass it through your loop arguments.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'orderby'=> 'menu_order'
'paged'=>$paged,
'numberposts' => 10
) ); ?>
```

**EDIT:**

I would have recommended the `showposts` which should do the job but it deprecated.

```
function get_posts($args = null)
{
    $defaults = array('numberposts' => 5);
    $r = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

    if (!empty($r['numberposts']))
        $r['posts_per_page'] = $r['numberposts'];

    $get_posts = new WP_Query;
    return $get_posts->query($r);
}
```

Comment: But i want limit total post. For example: I have 20 post. and i only want get 10 post and paging them (4 post per view)

Comment: I try `'numberposts' => 10` and `'showposts' => 10` But it not working?

Comment: @DeLe Can i get more information about the error message your getting? Set wordpress in debug mode and post your error.